# How to communicate between microservices using event bus?

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, microservices, event-bus

I'm trying to send data from one microservice to another through event bus. But still as a result I'm getting an empty data, I don't get what I'm doing wrong, please help.

Trying to send data:

```
app.get ('/products', async (req , res) => {
    let db = await connect();

    let cursor = await db.collection('posts').find({});
    let doc = await cursor.toArray();
    
    res.json(doc);
    if (doc.insertedCount == 1) {
        res.send({
            status: 'success',
            id: results.insertedId,
        });
    } 
    else {
        res.send({
            status: 'fail',
        });
    }
axios.get('http://localhost:4205/events', {
            type: 'Success',
            data: {
                _id: mongo.ObjectID(id),
                doc,
                postId: req.params.id,
            }
    
        })
});
```

Event bus:

```
app.get('/events', async (req, res) => {
    const event = req.body;
    res.json(event);
    axios.get('http://localhost:4202/events', event)
    res.send({status:'OK'})
})
```

Microservice where I want to fetch the data:

```
app.get('/events', async (req, res) => {
    
    res.send(req.body)
});
```

Comment: Second param for **axios.get** is config with options like: **params** and **headers**, what mean **type** and **data** in your case ?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, **EventBus** is about **emmiting** event and **listening** it, in your case it's like a simple **REST API**

Comment: Yeah, that's right, well I followed some example, I'm trying to send some data from same get method, I updated my question because this `axios.get` function is inside `app.get`, so can you try to correct what's wrong?

Comment: The first one is running on port 4200, the second one on 4205 (Event Bus) and trying to pass it on the third one which is running on 4202.

Comment: In witch one you get empty data? **debug** your responses.

Comment: Even in my Event bus (with `req.body`) I get an empty data, so I can't even assume what I'm sending wrong.

Comment: In the first one something is being sent wrong, even in console I don't get any errors.

Comment: You should use **post** instead of **get** to send data in **req.body**

Comment: Okay, so I need to use `post` just in the first one? And in others to `get`? And I'm still getting the empty data.

Comment: just `axios.post`, right?

Comment: I will create an example as answer.

Comment: Sure! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```js
app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const db = await connect();
        const cursor = await db.collection('posts').find({});
        const doc = await cursor.toArray();

    /*  Below are weird code
      res.json(doc);
      if (doc.insertedCount == 1) {
        res.send({
          status: 'success',
          id: results.insertedId,
        });
      } else {
        res.send({
          status: 'fail',
        });
      }
    */

        axios.post('http://localhost:4205/events', {
            type: 'Success',
            data: {
                id: mongo.ObjectID(id),
                doc,
                postId: req.params.id,
            },
        });

        return res.status(200).send();
  } catch (error) {
    // Here catch and do something with errors;
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Second:

```js
app.post('/events', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const event = req.body;
    console.log(event);

    // What's mean next line ?
    // res.json(event);

    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:4202/events', event);
    console.log(response);
    
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 'OK' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Last

```js
app.post('/events', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    
    return res.status(200).json(req.body);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me when I check that post in `postman` of last microservice , it's empty still , I want them to be written as a response, not as a request. And my `req.body` is empty in Event Bus. But communication between microservice and event bus works. Can you help me with sending data properly?

Comment: That weird code you commented, my fault, it stands `doc` instead of `results`, it allows to display at least one post, otherwise it wont work.